# Do orphaned processes get a new parent in Windows?

Tags: windows, process, parent-child, child-process

In Windows, when a parent process is killed, do children of that parent get a new parent?
Is it predictable what will happen in this situation?

Also, is there anyway to tell that those orphaned processes where once children?

Comment: Processes in Windows do not have a parent-child relationship so the question is moot.

Comment: @RaymondChen, then what's the meaning of the `th32ParentProcessID` member in the `PROCESSENTRY32` structure?

Comment: @RaymondChen, furthermore, the ProcessExplorer utility can display the running processes in a hierarchical tree, representing the parent-child relationships.

Comment: @Getfree, Windows 8+ actively maintains nested job objects for managing groups of processes. No version of Windows maintains a process tree. The parent process ID is set when a process is created, but not updated when the parent exits. It can be useful for a process manager/explorer to build a process tree by enumerating all running processes and linking parent to child, after sanity checking timestamps since PIDs can be reused. But once the parent exits, its child processes can no longer be linked into the tree. They form orphaned trees.

Comment: @eryksun, you are kind of answering the question, but in comment form.

Comment: Is this just a theoretical question, or do you have a real problem you're trying to solve? As to comments vs answers, I can replace comments on the question with an answer. Or someone else can add an answer. I don't much care about the points, reputation, and credit.

Comment: @eryksun, I needed to understand what happens in the following scenario: given process `A` which creates process `B` which in turn creates process `C` (forming the descendancy `A` -> `B` -> `C`), can `C` know that it's a descendant of `A` even if `B` no longer exists.

Comment: `C` does not know that it's a descendant of `A` if `B` exits -- not unless the processes are designed to work together and maintain this information.

Comment: @eryksun, I already have working code that allow process `C` to know that it's a descendant of `A`. I used the technique you described in a previous comment.

Comment: I think orphaned processes are claimed by windows only in cases where the application has a mechanism to find a orphaned process that it is supposed to handle. This was also highlighted by Mark Russinovich(Windows Sysinternals Author) in one of his talks and not sure if it is predictable whether it will get a new parent or gets killed or continue to be orphaned, this will largely depend upon the underlying application which launched this process to begin with.